# Calligra with czech accents ž, \v{z}

Tags: fonts, accents, calligraphy

is there any possibility that `\calligra` font will write chzech words like for example ž `\v{z}` ?

I use 
`\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}, 
\usepackage{calligra}` and it wrote words like á `\'{a}`, bud did't  ž `\v{z}`.

I tried `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but it didn't help.

Is there any possibility to write this words in `\calligra`?

Thank U very much, have a nice day.

Comment: Welcome! Please give us a [complete Minimum Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2):

The [font table](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/calligra/testfont.pdf) shows all of the glyphs present in the font.

For LaTeX to typeset a character in a certain font, it must either be supported directly by the font e.g. the character is `@` and the font contains an `@` symbol. Or, it must be possible to construct the character from characters the font does supply e.g. the character is `ŵ` and there's no `ŵ` in the font but there is a `w` and a `^` accent suitable for combining with the `w`.

Unfortunately, neither of these situations applies to `ž`. In theory, I guess you could use a rotated `^` accent. However, you would either need to prepare a special virtual font and install it, or you would need to define a suitable command for producing it. The former would be better than the latter, but a lot more work. And neither is likely to give entirely satisfactory results.

Here is a sampler of the non-rotated accent:

[image: little roofs]

I'm not sure this would work terribly well rotated...? When I tried it, it looked almost identical, if not identical, to the non-rotated version so you might as well type `\^z`:

[image: z and z with a little roof: right way up or upside down?]

Comment: Thank U, that solved my problem. I'll use {\^z} instead of ž, in this font it looks almost same. Thank U.